# javascript Remove value from array, array problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fill an array with strings, the elements that will be added are the HTML of the clicked <\li>, im probably filling it correctly.

My problem is when the user clicks on the checked link again, i want to remove this item from the array

Here is a code sample:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var chosen = [];
    var chosenCounter = 0;

            find("ul").find("li").click(function(){
        var checkBox = $(this).find("img").first();
        var checkBoxSrc = checkBox.attr("src");
        if(checkBoxSrc == "images/unchecked.png"){
            checkBoxSrc = "images/checked.png";
            checkBox.attr("src",checkBoxSrc);
            checkBox = "";
            checkBoxSrc = "";
            var temp = this.outerHTML;
            chosen[chosenCounter] = temp;
            chosenCounter ++;
        }
        if(checkBoxSrc == "images/checked.png"){
            checkBoxSrc = "images/unchecked.png";
            checkBox.attr("src",checkBoxSrc);
            checkBox = "";
            checkBoxSrc = "";



    for (var j =0; j<=chosen.length; j++){
            var tempRemove = this.outerHTML;
            chosen.splice( chosen.indexOf( tempRemove ), 1 );
            tempRemove = '';
        }
    }
});
```

});

I have been trying all functions and ways i found on internet .. but the results doesn't works well, i would be very thankful for a correction and explanation.
Thanks all in advance.

Comment: what are you doing with this array of html strings? If you have no way to track where it's contents come how can you use it?

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through an rewritten the code to work much better. There were a number of issues but here is the fixed version that I tested.

- Your original code had an **if** statement and then another **if** statement. You needed an if and then an **else if**.
- Notice when finding the child element I just use $('img', this) instead of the find operator and first().
- Use ID instead of HTML
- For debugging there is a console.log statement in there. Remove this so it works in IE.
- To add an element to an array use **push**
- No need to loop over splice to remove the item. Just call splice once.

  $(document).ready(function () {

  ```
  var chosenIDs = [];

  $("ul li").click(function () {
      var checkBox = $('img', this);
      var checkBoxSrc = checkBox.attr("src");
      var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
      console.log(id + ' ' + chosenIDs.length + ' ' + checkBoxSrc);

      if (checkBoxSrc == "images/unchecked.png") {
          checkBoxSrc = "images/checked.png";
          checkBox.attr("src", checkBoxSrc);

          chosenIDs.push(id);
      }
      else if (checkBoxSrc == "images/checked.png") {
          checkBoxSrc = "images/unchecked.png";
          checkBox.attr("src", checkBoxSrc);

          chosenIDs.splice(chosenIDs.indexOf(id), 1);
      }
  });
  ```

  });

Comment: each <li> has a unique id indeed, but i need to store the HTML to show the chosen <li> ONLY later on, i'm not a javascript ninja, so my idea was to store the chosen <li> in array and output them in a seperate <div><ul> when the user want to see the results, i am able to save these <li> but the problem is that the user has the ability to uncheck them, so my problem is how to remove this unchecked <li> from the array.

Comment: I think now i have understood the reason you are trying to explain, perhaps you can help more, i will try explain my "goal": big list of <li> and each <li> has its unique id, user can click and the <li> just like checkboxes, the purpose is that in the end of this procedure, i want to show ONLY the chosen <li> in a seperated div .. any help ?

Comment: I've converted your code so that it works with IDs in my updated answer.